# ColdBox view Query output error "can not cast complex object type query :string"

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee, coldbox

I'm getting my query output in modal and handler but when it comes to view it is saying

> can't cast complex object type query :string

in my coldbox

Comment: Without relevant code, there isn't much anyone can do.

Comment: I'm unable to dump also in my view

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to print something. The error is because to you can't print complex objects (query,structure,array, etc..) like that. So you have print it as `#yourQueryName.columnName#`. You can dump a complex object, but can't print it.

For example.

```
<cfset myQry = queryNew("Name,Age","varchar,integer",[{name='kannan',age="29"}])>
```

Now you can print the query data like

```
<cfoutput>MyName: #myQry.name# <br/>
    MyAge: #myQry.age#<br/>
</cfoutput>
```

But you can't directly print `#myQry#`  or it will return the error you're seeing. Instead, you can dump the query like this `<cfdump var="#myQry#" />`.

Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: You can only access `query.columnName` if you have an iteration context (e.g. `<cfloop query="query">`). To access a query without iteration context, you have to specify the row as well: `query["columnName"][rowIndex]`

Comment: *You can only access query.columnName if you have an iteration context*  More specifically, you can only access the values within the first row of a query. Anything else requires some sort of loop or specifying a row number.